# Strange error with Rect value after I set

Tags: opencv

[image]

As you can see, I created a Rect instance, but the value became strange after i set the x, y value t0 200 ,200. Can someone provide some suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: what's twidth , theight ? you're probably out of bounds

Comment: It looks like your Debugger is not set correct. What compiler enviroment do use? Check that Debug information has been created and you are running in Debug mode

Comment: both of twidth and theight is 9; As Tobias said, I output trect.x and ... by console, it seems some error with Debug mode. but when i run to imshow("PartPattern", ttmat). It crashed with "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed<mat.isContinuous<>> in unknow function ,file ..\..\..\modules\core\src\opengl_interop.cpp, line 1153".